# SVC' object has no attribute 'feature_importances_'

Tags: python

when i run this code it print error message like this

```
featimp = pd.Series(model.feature_importances_, index=prediction_var).sort_values(ascending=False)
```

print(featimp)

AttributeError: 'SVC' object has no attribute 'feature_importances_'

Comment: [sklearn.svm.SVC](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn-svm-svc) does not have any `feature_importances_` attribute, u will get that in tree based algorithms [RF](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.feature_importances_), [DT](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.feature_importances_) etc..